# MongoDB Atlas User Authentication using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-replica-set

I have a MongoDB Atlas instance, and am able to connect to it, but I am unable to create an account and access the DB from node.js. I can access the DB from Mongo Shell, after using the mongo command below & > 'use mytestcollection'.  Trying to access my testcollection directly from shell return 'Error Authentication Failed'.

Here'e the Shell Connection String..

```
mongo mongodb://<atlasDB>-1-shard-00-00-<string>.mongodb.net:27017,<atlasDB>-1-shard-00-01-<string>.mongodb.net:27017,<atlasDB>-1-shard-00-02-<string>.mongodb.net:27017/admin?replicaSet=<atlasDB>-1-shard-0 --ssl --username <account>  --password <password>
```

Here's the Node.js Code

```
var uri = "mongodb://<atlasDB>-1-shard-00-00-<string>.mongodb.net:27017,"+
                    "<atlasDB>-1-shard-00-01-<string>.mongodb.net:27017,"+
                    "<atlasDB>-1-shard-00-02-<string>.mongodb.net:27017/mytestcollection?"+
                    "replicaSet=-1-shard-0"+
                    "&ssl=true"+
                    "&authSource=<admin>"+
                    "&username=<account>"+
                    "&password=<password>"
```

and the Node Code is...

```
MongoDB.connect(uri,function(e,db) { 
        if ( e ) { console.error('Mongo Failed'); return console.log(e); } 
        console.log('MongoSuccess');
        db.collection('mytestcollection').find().toArray(function(e,d) {
             if ( e ) { console.log('error'); console.log(e);  }
             if ( d ) { console.log('test.length',d.length); }
        });
 });
```

And the error is...

```
MongoSuccess
error
{ MongoError: not authorized on test to execute command { find: "mytestcollection", filter: {} }
at Function.MongoError.create (/home/ec2-user/frame/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
at queryCallback (/home/ec2-user/frame/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:206:36)
at /home/ec2-user/frame/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:430:18
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'not authorized on test to execute command { find: "mytestcollection", filter: {} }',
ok: 0,
errmsg: 'not authorized on test to execute command { find: "mytestcollection", filter: {} }',
code: 13 }
```

Any Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You need to shuffle the [MongoDB URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-uri-format) for `username` and `password` to authenticate properly.
Also you need to specify database name before the `replicaSet` param, instead of collection name. See [Standard Connection String Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format) for more information on how to format MongoDB URI.

Based on your example:

```
var uri = "mongodb://[username:password@]<atlasDB>-1-shard-00-00-<string>.mongodb.net:27017,"+
                "<atlasDB>-1-shard-00-01-<string>.mongodb.net:27017,"+
                "<atlasDB>-1-shard-00-02-<string>.mongodb.net:27017/databaseName?"+
                "replicaSet=-1-shard-0"+
                "&ssl=true"+
                "&authSource=<admin>";

MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
        if ( e ) { console.error('Connection Failed'); return console.log(e); } 
        console.log("Connected");

        db.collection('collectionName').find().toArray(function(e,d) {
             if ( e ) { console.log('error'); console.log(e);  }
             console.log(d);
        });

        db.close();    
});
```

The above snippet was tested using [MongoDB Node.js driver v2.2](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/quick-start/)

See also:

- [MongoDB Node tutorial: authenticating](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/connect/authenticating/)
- [MongoDB Node tutorial: ssl connection](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/connect/ssl/)